# How to create a child by one SQL-request in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

If an author has many books ("one to many" relationship) and I want to create a child by `$author_id` I should do this:

```
$author = Author::find($author_id);
$author->books()->create([...]);
```

But this code produces two SQL-requests as well as this:

```
Author::find($author_id)->books()->create([...]);
```

To reduce the number of SQL-requests I should add `author_id` field into the `$fillable` array in my Book model and do this:

```
Book::create([
    'author_id' => $author_id,
    ...
]);
```

Which approach is better? As for me, the first one looks more correct, more Eloquent way, but 2 SQL-requests are too much for such simple case. Are there any other ways to make only one SQL-request without touching the `$fillable` array?

Comment: for saving data in One SQL query you should use Second approach.

Answer (score 0):

The old school:

```
$book = new Book;
$book->author_id = $author_id;
//...
$book->save();
```

Or you could [`forceCreate`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_forceCreate), which bypasses fillable:

```
Book::forceCreate(['author_id' => $author_id, ...]);
```

As for which approach is better: if you know the `author_id`, then 2nd (without using the relationship). But from my experience, that's rarely the case, since you usually want to check whether the related model actually exists. But if you're confident in the correctness of your input, no need for 2 queries.